# Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?

Tags: symfony

I recenetly installed elasticsearch bundle and i configured it like in the documentation:
fos_elastica.yml

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    Leimen:
        client: default
        types:
            Article:
                mappings:
                    id:
                        type: integer
                    date: ~
                    title: ~
                    author: ~
                    content: ~
                    email: ~
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Leimen\SiteBundle\Entity\Article
                    finder: ~
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
```

when i run `fos:elastica:populate`
I got this error
`[Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException]
Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?`

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: You sure that elasticsearch server is running?

Comment: How can i know that?When i run with elastic_port there is no error!

Comment: On what system your work? Linux/Mac/Windows?

Comment: i am under Windows.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instal and run `Elasticsearch` server on your computer/server. It's not installed by `Elastica`.

How to install: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html

Comment: Thnkx;i am going to see this doc,Thank you very much Pawel.